# Getting stored procedure returned value instead of row affected

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a stored procedure which does an insert and returns (for e.g. StudentID) of the last row inserted.

```
 create procedure insertStudent
 @...
 insert into ... values...
 set @StudentId = scope_identity();
 select StudentId from ... where StudentId = @StudentId
```

In the code, I have

```
var sql = ...;
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
{
  var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
  parameters.Add ...;
  ...
  int studentId = connection.Execute(sql, parameters, commandType : CommandType.StoredProcedure);
  ...
}
```

connection.Execute returns the number of rows affected.

How can I get the StudentId which the stored procedure is returning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Query`, not `Execute`. Execute is meant for queries that don't return values.

The docs in Dapper's repository show how to call a stored procedure that returns  results :

```
var user = cnn.Query<User>("spGetUser", new {Id = 1}, 
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();
```

You can simplify your stored procedure too. INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE have an [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) that can be used to return the original and replaced values by querying the `inserted` and `deleted` virtual tables :

```
 insert into ... 
 OUTPUT inserted.StudentID
 values...
```

Your code could be simplified to :

```
  int studentId = connection.Query<int>("insertStudent", parameters, commandType : CommandType.StoredProcedure)
                            .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much!